# How practically did large farmers manage presenting their bikkurim?

Tags: bikkurim-first-fruits

The minimum shiur for bikkurim miderabbonon is one-sixtieth - see the answer to [this question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/45359/how-much-produce-becomes-bikkurim-first-fruits?noredirect=1#comment120039_45359).

One sixtieth of the harvest for a farmer of a sizable farm would be difficult to fit into even seven baskets - one for each of the seven species.

How practically did large farmers manage presenting their bikkurim?

Comment: similar http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/2617/759

Answer (score 3):

My Rov suggested that the requirement to present bikkurim in a basket in biblical. According to the Torah there is no minimum shiur for bikkurim. So even the owner of a large farm can manage with one or more baskets (up to seven).

The shiur of 1/60 th is rabbinic and maybe the excess over the Torah shiur doesn't need a basket etc.

Comment: Any sources for this?

Comment: I see no indication of such a distinction in the Rambam

Comment: No sources and yes I don't see it in the Rambam. Feel free to post your own answers.

Answer (score 1):

In derech emuna
reb chaim k asks this and says that 1/60 is not based on time of harvest
but rather on the time when he saw fruit in early bloom as it says in the mishnah